# Use radiobuttons inside mask for Simulink-MatLab function

Tags: matlab, user-interface, interface, simulink

[My Simulink-MatLab function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuLSm.png)

[My interface from "mask" for the functin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtCzu.png)

Now here is the question: I made the interface with different values and radio buttons, how can I use them behind the mask (inside the code)?
I have to make a code that takes action related to the status of radio buttons and also other values, somehow I cannot find how to ref. to them inside the code.

Example how it could be used:

```
switch state 

 if **radiobutton1=Auto**
  state=0
   elseif **radiobutton=manual**
  state=1
 end

case 0 
   action1....
case1
   action2....
end
```

It is also those ** marked commands I cannot understand how to write so that the program understands.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified example

```
function y = MaskTestFcn(u,v,w, mode)
    disp(mode);
    if mode == 1 %Manual
        y = [0,0,0];
    else
        y = [u,v,w];
    end
end
```

This function has 3 variables that are set as "Input" `u,v,w`, and `mode` which is set as a "Parameter" from the "Edit Data" menu inside the MATLAB function's editor.

To add a new parameter, go to the "Edit Data" option and click Add -> Data. From the new data that appears, set the "Scope" to "Parameter".

The radio box will return 1 for the first option, 2 for the second option etc.